# Reading through a table row by row in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have a table that I want to read row by row to search for a specific match.

Here are the result of my table and the columns. `Pos_Scan` represents what is scanned at the point of sale and how many

```
UniqueID   INGREDINETID          KITCHENITEMID       QUANTITY  POS_SCAN    STATUS
1          510                   0111                1         5           0
2          54491472              0111                1         2           0
3          6001069201906         6006749006031       1         0           0 
4          54491472              6006749006031       1         5           0
```

HAS more than these records here what i want to do is to be able to loop through this table and pull out rows that have the same `kitchenitemid` and have `pos_scan >= quantity` this is to form a complete recipe for example row 1 and 2 will be a complete recipe but row 3 and 4 will not be a recipe because `pos_scan` for `ingredientid` at uniqueid 3 is 0

please help me

thank you

Comment: Pos_scan is always zero; pos_scan >= quantity is never true. Please post another example.

Comment: @user1285279: What have you tried?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović: The column headings were misaligned - they should be correct now.

Comment: Reading a table "row by row" is never a requirement. Is the actual requirement something like "identify `kitchenitemid`s, such that all rows with the `id` have `pos_scan` >= `quantity`" (or is it the opposite result you're seeking - find the `id`s such that *not* all rows have `pos_scan` >= `quantity`?

Comment: "Reading a table "row by row" is never a requirement." Printed and hung on my wall :)

Answer (score 1):

If my reconstructed requirement suggestions in the comments are close to right, then something like the following would do:

```
 SELECT
     KitchenItemID,MIN(Satisfied),MAX(Satisfied)
 FROM
    (
         SELECT
             KitchenItemID,
             CASE WHEN pos_scan >= Quantity THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Satisfied
         FROM
             OriginalTableNotNamdInQuestion
    ) t
 GROUP BY
     KitchenItemID
 HAVING
     MIN(Satisfied) = MAX(Satisfied) --Change this to < to find incomplete "recipes"
```